# Wordpress post date hook

Tags: wordpress, date, post, hook

I still can't get my head around hooks but I assume a hook might do what I need.

Currently using WP Show Posts to short code into a home page, that uses WPBakery as the page builder.
WP Show Posts can pull in post header, date, excerpt and button link. 
I want to hook the date (post publish date) to the post Advanced Custom Field i.e. event date. this is the development site https://dev.itassetalliance.com/
Webinars category post. changing default wordpress the_date()  to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you should be able to use `get_the_date` filter, more [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/get_the_date).  Below is a quick example of how you might do this:

```
<?php
// hook into get_the_date filter
add_filter('get_the_date', function ($post_date) {

  // get event date
  $event_date = get_field('event_date');

  // may need to use some other check here
  // but this if we have $event_date return
  // it in place of the default post date
  if ($event_date) {
    return $event_date;
  }

  // if we did not return an event date
  // then return the default date
  return $post_date;
});
?>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I am not sure what the variable is for $event.
The $event_date = get_field('webinar_date_&_time'); 
webinar_date_&_time is the custom field but beyond that I am a little lost. Sorry, real noob when it comes to hooks so not sure where I need to look, to get this information

Comment: Sorted it thank you. Learning.

Comment: 1 question. how to do you get this filter to show on homepage but still visible as the custom field on a post but not change the post date on blog post/page
'code'
  if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) {
 if ($webinar_date_time) {
    return $webinar_date_time;
  }
}
'/code'
thanks

Comment: If I understand the question in the comments... You want to limit the display of the `$webinar_date_time` to just the homepage?

Comment: Thanks for everyones replies and apologies for the delay. this worked
'code' // hook into get_the_date filter
add_filter('get_the_date', function ($post_date) {

  // get event date
  $webinar_date_time = get_field('webinar_date_time');

  // may need to use some other check here
  // but this if we have $event_date return
  // it in place of the default post date
  // 
 if ( is_page( array( '14' ) )  )  {
 if ($webinar_date_time) {
    return $webinar_date_time;
  }
 }
  // if we did not return an event date
  // then return the default date
  return $post_date;
}); '/code'